# Tweepy stream.filter using cashtags

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Can you filter using `$` cashtags using the free version of the twitter API?

- Does it pull out exact matches (i.e. must include `$GSK`) or approximate matches?
- Does it just match the text? or the actual cashtag?

For example:

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["$GSK", "$BARC"], languages=["en"])
```

When I run it I seem to be pulling in tweets on stocks that I have not selected?

As an aside does the tweepy use v2 of the Twitter API?

Comment: There's a pull request for Tweepy to support v2, but it has not been merged as I type this today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that cashtag is only available for enterprise search APIs as of now. See [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/search-api/guides/operators).

[image]